# Apache camel setHeader in spring xml dsl

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I just have assigned to apache camel project in the company where I work. The project is with spring xml dsl. I'm curious about strange behaviour of the attribute for name in the setHeader element. Eclipse is marking the attribute with name 'headerName' as invalid and want me to use just 'name'. However everywhere in the project the setHeader is with headerName and it works. I also have checked in camel.apache.org for Set Header EIP and the only option there is really just 'name'. Can someone please explain how it works with 'headerName' and why?

```
<setHeader headerName="var1">
    <constant>value1</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Comment: In Camel 3 there was a change and headerName became name. Eclipse is probably using the wrong xsd to validate your route. It is a false positive from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use the schema definition of version you use.
Eg.: Use camel-spring-2.17.7.xsd instead of camel-spring.xsd